# How to have AngularJS route with same url hit a different controller function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Very confused and not sure if I am thinking about it correctly. Please let me know what else I need to show for this to make sense...

I have two different functions in mongoose. One indexes all listings and the other indexes unique user listings and is filtered in my mongoose function. However, in my routes, how do I hit the unique function when on my profile page if the $http url is the same?

```
//From server.js to controllers
app.get('/api/listings', controllers.listings.index);

//all listings shown on home page
function index (req, res) {
  db.Listing.find({}, function(err, allListings) {
    res.json(allListings);
  });
}

//From server.js to controllers
app.get('/api/listings/', auth.ensureAuthenticated, controllers.profiles.indexUnique);

//unique function that I want to show on profile page only
function indexUnique(req, res) {
  db.User.findById(req.user, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {console.log(err);}
    db.Listing.find({uid: req.user}, function(err, listings) {
      if(err) { console.log('Error', err); }
      res.json(listings);
    });
  })
}
```

How do I adjust my http request to hit my unique function if the url routes are the same?

```
// Angular http request in my home controller
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/listings'
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    vm.listings = response.data;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log('Error getting data', response);
  });
```

Comment: I recommend you to use parameter for the unique one i.e.
/api/listings/:listingId. Then you can send request with parameter listingId. This is the restfull way and easy to understand. I could not understand why you wanna use same url.

Comment: You can also use this library. This is very useful for consuming apis in meaningful way :  https://github.com/mgonto/restangular

Answer (score 0):

you could do the filtering on angular as a service and keep two separate arrays of objects